# Rundeck Static Token not loaded when Rundeck Service is started

Tags: rundeck

I think my Rundeck does not load my **tokens.properties** file. I can't see it on my service.log being loaded. [Here is a screenshot of the log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8yaV.png)

That's why when I restart the service or the server my scheduled jobs, that triggers Rundeck API, always get this error

```
{"error":true,"apiversion":35,"errorCode":"api.error.item.unauthorized","message":"Not authorized for action \"Run\" for Job ID 109fd435-765f-4b7a-a547-0c5906c4a1f5"}
```

For it to work properly again, I need to generate a new token each time I restart Rundeck or the server. I have already included this line in my **framework.properties**

```
rundeck.tokens.file=C:/rundeck/etc/tokens.properties
```

And in my **tokens.properties**, it has 1 line only which is

```
atrsdk-runner: token_string
```

How can I make my token permanent? Did I miss something here, how will I fix this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the role on `tokens.properties` file. I tested on a Windows machine and works in this way:

1. Stop the Rundeck service.
2. On `framework.properties` file add:

```
rundeck.tokens.file=C:/rundeck/tokens.properties
```

3. On `realm.properties` file add (just an example user for testing):

```
bob:bob,admin
```

4. Create a file named `tokens.properties` at `c:\rundeck\` path with the following content (i added the role at the end of the line):

```
bob: 12345, admin
```

5. Start the Rundeck service.
6. With this API call you can run the job using the custom token (check the `rdeck_token` variable, tested on an external Linux host running [cURL](https://curl.haxx.se/)):

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# protocol
protocol="http"

# basic rundeck info
rdeck_host="10.0.1.81"
rdeck_port="4440"
rdeck_api="36"
rdeck_token="12345"

# specific api call info
rdeck_job="91c5b968-166f-4138-9345-580cd624adda"

# api call
curl -s --location --request POST "$protocol://$rdeck_host:$rdeck_port/api/$rdeck_api/job/$rdeck_job/run" \
  --header "Accept: application/json" \
  --header "X-Rundeck-Auth-Token: $rdeck_token" \
  --header "Content-Type: application/json"
```

Now, without a role defined at `tokens.properties` file I obtain your error (the output was "beautified" with [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)):

```json
{
  "error": true,
  "apiversion": 36,
  "errorCode": "api.error.item.unauthorized",
  "message": "Not authorized for action \"Run\" for Job ID 91c5b968-166f-4138-9345-580cd624adda"
}
```

And with the role defined at `tokens.properties` file (successful):

```json
{
  "id": 3,
  "href": "http://10.0.1.81:4440/api/36/execution/3",
  "permalink": "http://10.0.1.81:4440/project/ProjectBOB/execution/show/3",
  "status": "running",
  "project": "ProjectBOB",
  "executionType": "user",
  "user": "bob",
  "date-started": {
    "unixtime": 1603801591299,
    "date": "2020-10-27T12:26:31Z"
  },
  "job": {
    "id": "91c5b968-166f-4138-9345-580cd624adda",
    "averageDuration": 1727,
    "name": "HelloWorld",
    "group": "",
    "project": "ProjectBOB",
    "description": "",
    "href": "http://10.0.1.81:4440/api/36/job/91c5b968-166f-4138-9345-580cd624adda",
    "permalink": "http://10.0.1.81:4440/project/ProjectBOB/job/show/91c5b968-166f-4138-9345-580cd624adda"
  },
  "description": "echo \"hi\"",
  "argstring": null,
  "serverUUID": "2337f5f7-e951-47d2-ba62-f8c02a0bb8df"
}
```

And [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdXbs.jpg) the execution on Rundeck.

Comment: Hello @MegaDrive68k, I've tried adding the roles in the token.properties but I'm still getting the unauthorized error. my token.properties looks like these now: `atrsdk-runner: token_string,role_1,role_2,role_3` and atrsdk-runner is also existing in the realm.properties.

Comment: Thanks for always helping @MegaDrive68k. It's working now. I had a typo in the roles the reason I'm still getting 403 but when I corrected the spelling of my roles It's working perfectly now.

Comment: Any time roboragi :-)