# Auto-create Rundeck jobs on startup (Rundeck in Docker container)

Tags: docker, ansible, rundeck

I'm trying to setup Rundeck inside a Docker container. I want to use Rundeck to provision and manage my Docker fleet. I found an image which ships an ansible-plugin as well. So far running simple playbooks and auto-discovering my Pi nodes work.

Docker script:

```
echo "[INFO] prepare rundeck-home directory"
mkdir ../../target/work/home
mkdir ../../target/work/home/rundeck
mkdir ../../target/work/home/rundeck/data

echo -e "[INFO] copy host inventory to rundeck-home"
cp resources/inventory/hosts.ini ../../target/work/home/rundeck/data/inventory.ini

echo -e "[INFO] pull image"
docker pull batix/rundeck-ansible

echo -e "[INFO] start rundeck container"
docker run -d \
    --name rundeck-raspi \
    -p 4440:4440 \
    -v "/home/sebastian/work/workspace/workspace-github/raspi/target/work/home/rundeck/data:/home/rundeck/data" \
    batix/rundeck-ansible
```

Now I want to feed the container with playbooks which should become jobs to run in Rundeck. Can anyone give me a hint on how I can create Rundeck jobs (which should invoke an ansible playbook) from the outside? Via api?

One way I can think of is creating the jobs manually once and exporting them as XML or YAML. When the container and Rundeck is up and running I could import the jobs automatically. Is there a certain folder in rundeck-home or somewhere where I can put those files for automatic import? Or is there an API call or something?

Could Jenkins be more suited for this task than Rundeck?

---

**EDIT:** just changed to a Dockerfile

```
FROM batix/rundeck-ansible:latest

COPY resources/inventory/hosts.ini /home/rundeck/data/inventory.ini
COPY resources/realms.properties /home/rundeck/etc/realms.properties
COPY resources/tokens.properties /home/rundeck/etc/tokens.properties


# import jobs
ENV RD_URL="http://localhost:4440"
ENV RD_TOKEN="yJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIs"
ENV rd_api="36"
ENV rd_project="Test-Project"
ENV rd_job_path="/home/rundeck/data/jobs"
ENV rd_job_file="Ping_Nodes.yaml"

# copy job definitions and script
COPY resources/jobs-definitions/Ping_Nodes.yaml /home/rundeck/data/jobs/Ping_Nodes.yaml
RUN curl -kSsv --header "X-Rundeck-Auth-Token:$RD_TOKEN" \
    -F yamlBatch=@"$rd_job_path/$rd_job_file" "$RD_URL/api/$rd_api/project/$rd_project/jobs/import?fileformat=yaml&dupeOption=update"
```

Do you know how I can delay the curl at the end until after the rundeck service is up and running?

Answer (score 1):

That's right you can design an script with an [API](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/api/rundeck-api.html) call using [cURL](https://linux.die.net/man/1/curl) (pointing to your Docker instance) after deploying your instance (a script that deploys your instance and later import the jobs), I leave a basic example (in this example you need the job definition in XML format).

For XML job definition format:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# protocol
protocol="http"

# basic rundeck info
rdeck_host="localhost"
rdeck_port="4440"
rdeck_api="36"
rdeck_token="qNcao2e75iMf1PmxYfUJaGEzuVOIW3Xz"

# specific api call info
rdeck_project="ProjectEXAMPLE"
rdeck_xml_file="HelloWorld.xml"

# api call
curl -kSsv --header "X-Rundeck-Auth-Token:$rdeck_token" \
  -F xmlBatch=@"$rdeck_xml_file" "$protocol://$rdeck_host:$rdeck_port/api/$rdeck_api/project/$rdeck_project/jobs/import?fileformat=xml&dupeOption=update"
```

For YAML job definition format:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# protocol
protocol="http"

# basic rundeck info
rdeck_host="localhost"
rdeck_port="4440"
rdeck_api="36"
rdeck_token="qNcao2e75iMf1PmxYfUJaGEzuVOIW3Xz"

# specific api call info
rdeck_project="ProjectEXAMPLE"
rdeck_yml_file="HelloWorldYML.yaml"

# api call
curl -kSsv --header "X-Rundeck-Auth-Token:$rdeck_token" \
  -F xmlBatch=@"$rdeck_yml_file" "$protocol://$rdeck_host:$rdeck_port/api/$rdeck_api/project/$rdeck_project/jobs/import?fileformat=yaml&dupeOption=update"
```

[Here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/api/rundeck-api.html#importing-jobs) the API call.

Comment: Sounds good. Thanks. If I understand correctly I need an API token for alle rest calls right? Is there a way to get the token via script? I want to provision my whole rundeck from outside.

Comment: Sure, in your case, maybe the best approach is to provide an image with a static token (using a custom tokens.properties file referenced at framework.properties file), the process is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64552766/rundeck-static-token-not-loaded-when-rundeck-service-is-started/64554467#64554467

Comment: thanks ... do you by any chance know how the curl looks like for yml files?

Comment: Updated answer for YAML files :-)

Comment: great ... now one (hopefully) last question ... I changed the setup to a Dockerfile. I just updated my question and added the Dockerfile. Do you know how I can delay the curl at the end until after the rundeck service is up and running?

Comment: you can use a while loop waiting for rundeck service to start the job import, this code works for me: https://pastebin.com/hPMX230q

Comment: the while loop is helpful but still I cannot get my job-imports to run after rundeck service is up-and-running. I'm using `RUN sudo chmod +x /home/rundeck/data/jobs/run-import.sh` and `RUN /home/rundeck/data/jobs/run-import.sh` in my dockerfile. The run-script.sh contains your while loop and webservice call. But still the script is invoked to early (before rundeck is up and runnijg -> hence delaying the service start indefinitely). In Java I would use something like @PostConstruct ... Something to run after complete initialization.